# Unable to update contact's profile picture using Google's People API

Tags: python, google-people-api

So, i wrote this code:

```py
json_data = "{\"photoBytes\":" + str(bytearray(open("image.png", "rb").read())) + "}"
service.people().updateContactPhoto('people/c4942919248052589775', json_data)
```

but it gives me this error:
`TypeError: method() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`

I cannot understand why. As the [docs](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/people_v1.people.html#updateContactPhoto) say, I should use it like this...

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I abbandoned my project, but I will leave this thread open for anyone who needs help.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string value as a request body which should be in json format.

Try using json.dumps() first on your json_date before passing it as a parameter in updateContactPhoto().

Your code should look like this:

```
json_data = "{\"photoBytes\":" + str(bytearray(open("image.png", "rb").read())) + "}"
service.people().updateContactPhoto('people/c4942919248052589775', json.dumps(json_data))
```

Comment: I will try this tomorrow and I'll let you know if it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: Unfortunately I still get the same error. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out with a lot of trial and error and I found that the photo needs to be base64 encoded and the best method to get that into JSON below ([thanks to this answer for this tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57546533/1177153)).

Here's the working code for me below

```
import base64

JSON = """{
    "photoBytes": "%s"
}
""" % (base64.b64encode(open("test.png", "rb").read()).decode('utf-8'))

update_body = json.loads(JSON)

service.people().updateContactPhoto(resourceName="people/123456789", body=update_body).execute()
```

Comment: I will try this just to see if it works cause I already abandoned the project. Thank you so much for your effort into finding this answer. Even if it will not work (but I think it will) it's highly appreciated.